# Remove decimals from JSON string

Tags: java, android, json

I am making an app that gets weather info from the web.

I am getting the whole `JSONObject` at once, instead of piece by piece.
As a result of that, I can't call `.getDouble` for temperature, I call `getString`.

This returns a String, which I can't use the Math.round method on.
I tried the `.split(".")` and it returns an array out of bounds exception, when I try to instert the sting into a text view.

If I call `.toString()` it gives me "`[Ljava.lang.String;@7353879`" in the textview.

Comment: Why exactly can you not call `getDouble` on a `JSONObject`?

Comment: that's not a string, that's a string[]. post your json, and show the code you tried to use to split it and to parse it.

Comment: I can't call getDouble, because it doesn't let me, it says resource not found.

Comment: temp = mHourTest.getHour1().getString("temperature");
                        nodecimals = temp.split(".");
                        mHourlyTemp.setText(nodecimals[0]);

Comment: That's my .split() code, and it crashes with an arrayoutofbounds exception, when I add .toString() it returns [Ljava.lang.String;@7353879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand exactly what you mean , If you intend to convert json data to double or float you can use :

> Double.parseDouble(jsonObj.getString("x"));

or

> Float.praseFloat(jsonObj.getString("x"));

like this :

> float x = Float.praseFloat(jsonObj.getString("x"));

**Update My Answer**

for getting ride of decimal ....
you can do this :

> int x = ( (int) Double.parseDouble(objJson.getString("x")) );
>
> String result = x + "" ;

Comment: I need to remove decimals from a String. The JSONObject is where I get the string.

Comment: Why dont  you convert that double to int value , this should help you

Comment: I update my answer , i hope that work for you , please let me know if it works.

Comment: Works. Thank you very much!

Comment: I am happy that I could help you

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the text from the text field, you need to use the `.getText()` method, and then use `.toString()`

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to.

Comment: to your last point in your question. if you use .getText(), it returns a string.

Comment: I am not getting the text from a textview or an edittext, I am getting it from a JSONObject.